# The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I tried the container I put image.net work in the child it works but I need to custom border of the image. How should I fix it?

```
    Expanded(child: Align(alignment:Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          height: 45, //height, //155,
          width: 45, //width, //155,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
            image: DecorationImage(
            image: Image.network(state
              .offerConfirm
              .ownImage[index]),
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
         ),
        ),
      ),
     flex: 3,
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Change image decoration to :**

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage("urlImage"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover)
    ),
```

**Full code :**

```
Expanded(
                                            child: Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: 45, //height, //155,
                                                width: 45, //width, //155,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color:
                                                      const Color(0xff7c94b6),
                                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                                    image: NetworkImage(state
                                                        .offerConfirm
                                                        .ownImage[index])
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  ),
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            flex: 3,
                                          ),
```

Comment: can you please mark the answer correct? and also upvote so that other people can make use of it.

Comment: Sure bro, i have to wait around 10 min for mark.

Answer (score 2):

There can be three types of image widgets we can have in flutter,

1. Network Image

so use      `NetworkImage("http://imageURL"),`
in place of `Image.network("http://imageURL"),`

2. Asset Image
   so use            `AssetImage("assets/book_icon.png"),`
   in place of  `Image.asset('assets/skip-book_icon.png'),`
3. Memory Image,

so use      `MemoryImage(uint8listBytes),`
in place of `Image.memory(uint8listBytes),`